# Invalid JSON RPC Response with web3.eth.filter

Tags: web3js, transactions, pending-transactions

I'm trying to retrieve all pending transactions by using web3.eth.filter given an address, but i always receive "Invalid JSON RPC Response "" ".
Web3 version is 0.20.6.

I'm using rinkeby testnet.

```
var options = {
  from: "0x9596f1439576e0142976F0822883DE62e326B542",
};
var filter =  web3.eth.filter( options );

filter.watch(function (error, log) {
  if ( error )
    console.log(error.message);
  else {
    console.log(log);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have given valid http provider, the error may be it is not able to connect to the network with the provider